# Adding arbitrary types to an object at runtime

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

In our application we have an object that receives attributes at runtime.  For example, to add a float to the object:

```
my_object->f("volume") = 1.0f;
```

Retrieving the volume works the same way:

```
cout << my_object->f("volume") << endl;
```

Internally, this is represented by a map of strings to their respective type.  Each type has its own access methods and map.  It looks like this:

```
map<string, float> my_floats;
map<string, int> my_ints;
map<string, void *> my_void_pointers;
```

Oh, the dreaded `void *`.  Sometimes we need to add classes or functions to the object.  Rather than have a separate map for every conceivable type, we settled on a `void *` map.  The problem we're having is with cleanup.  Currently, we keep around a list of each type of these "dangling" objects that the `void *` point to, and call a cleanup function on these separate lists when necessary.

I don't like having to use `void *` and all the extra attention it requires for proper cleanup.  Is there some better way to store arbitrary types in an object at runtime,  accessible via a string map, and still benefit from automatic cleanup via destructor?

Comment: Have you looked at the [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) type?

Comment: Not yet.  Thanks for the link GWW.  I am admittedly not as well versed in boost as I should be -- the library is a bit intimidating if you're not sure exactly what to look for!

Comment: I agree there the documentation could definitely be better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post seems to be a good answer to your question.

[Storing a list of arbitrary objects in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607458/storing-a-list-of-arbitrary-objects-in-c)

Comment: Thank you!  Looks like either boost::variant or boost::any will do what I'm wanting.

Answer (score 5):

You are spoiled for choice here - boost::any or simply storing everything as std::string both come immediately to mind.

Comment: `boost::any` definitely being the win here.

Comment: @DeadMG Depends - maybe you don't want the dependency.

Comment: @Neil Can you explain what you mean by storing everything as std::string?  Do you mean to store the type as a string, and later on check that string against a list of known types and react accordingly?

Comment: @Neil: Even if you don't want to depend on Boost, the implementation can't be that big a deal.

Comment: @sinoth No, I mean convert the input data to a string and an enumerated type (or similar) and then convert it back on request, with suitable error checking. That's basically what all implementations of this sort of thing do, one way or another.

Comment: @Neil Ahh, gotcha.  The problem with that is I'm wanting to attach more complex things to the object, such as function pointers or other classes, that can't be easily represented by a string.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than storing a map to so many values, it would be better to use a boost::variant. After all, judging by your interface, it would not be legal for me to assign both an int and a float to the same string.

```
std::map<std::string, boost::variant<float, int, std::string, ...>>;
```